# javascript - Select dropdown onchange with "another select "

Tags: javascript, html

`my-select` is the main, when is chosen by users, it opens popup (what works right now), but what I
want is that when I choose `my-select2` it should change the value
too.

```
<select id="my-select">
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
</select>

<select id="my-select2">
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
</select>


document.getElementById('my-select').addEventListener('change', function() {
  console.log('You selected: ', this.value);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is a very simple way to do that.

In the change listener, you just simply call the other select and change it's selected index after applying your own logic.

Please check the code here:

```js
document.getElementById('my-select').addEventListener('change', function() {
  console.log('You selected: ', this.value);
  document.getElementById("my-select2").selectedIndex = this.selectedIndex;

});
```

```html
<select id="my-select">
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
</select>

<select id="my-select2">
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast and detailed answers , forget about eventlistener. work fine after implemented

Answer (score 1):

```
document.getElementById('my-select').addEventListener('change', function() {
  console.log('You selected: ', this.value);
  selectOptionInMySelect2(this.value)
});

function selectOptionInMySelect2(value) {

  const selectElement = document.getElementById('my-select2');
  const allOptions = selectElement.options;

  for(let i=0; i < allOptions.length; i++) {

    if(allOptions[i].value == value) {
      selectElement.selectedIndex = i;
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

Included the same ids and values as that in your snippet.
[Working example here](https://js-qyp88e.stackblitz.io)

Did not realise that an answer already got posted till the time I was editing this. Wow, community!

Just in case, **the option sequence isn't the same in both selects**, this will work. Cheers!